# Why can i see contours through a layer above in Adobe Illustrator CS5?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Adobe Illustrator CS5 for a simple game.

I do not know why, but I can see contours of my chair through my table. The table is a layer above the chair. The table is **not transparent**. Nevertheless I can see the contours of the chair through the table:

[image]

What setting is responsible for this behaviour?

Comment: Your objects are in wrong order.

Comment: @jooja. No. The chair is a layer below the table layer.

Comment: Than you have a blending mode issue, or you have 2 separate objects one for table and one for stroke.

Comment: @Simon can you provide a screenshot of the Attributes, Transparency and Layers panels while your chair and table are selected? Similar to [this example](http://i.imgur.com/Smc4fz1.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **stroke** applied via the **Appearance Panel** which is *above* the contents (group) in the panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the layers ordered well and you didn't use transparency .. so you are using a different color mode than `Normal` (most probably you are using `Darken` color mode)

I guess you tried to delete the table and draw it again giving the same effect. in that case your color mode is applied to the whole layer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience. But all layers have everywhere set the color mode to 'Normal'

Comment: sorry I don't have any solution in mind. except asking you to send me the file.

Comment: hsawires@gmail.com please let me know when you send it. to delete this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are seeing the object, and haven't accidentally hit "command+u" and are hovering the mouse over the chair?[image]

OR

Try selecting the object, go to view> attributes> and uncheck "overprint fill". Maybe you have your "view" set to Overprint preview, see below for settings:

[image: Overprint with Overprint Preview set to on]

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I am not hovering the Object with the mouse. I would notice that. Your second suggestion does not solve my problem.

Comment: I would try to copy the objects into a new file, and in the layer pallette, clear all the settings. That way you can rule out any object level settings. Once you have that out of the way, you can go through the View settings in the program itself, and see if the issue might be there.

Hope you figure it out. Seems annoying.